# Laravel: URL in string

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I want to print a button in my Laravel (blade) views. I have made a function for creating this button, because of: if the user, who loads the view, doesn't have rights to see this button, the button won't show up (I haven't made this part yet). In every view where I need a button for something, I want to use this method. The return value of the method is:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to(scholen/toevoegen) }}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Nieuwe school</button></a>
```

There is just a problem: the method `createButton()` returns a string. So, `{{ URL::to('scholen/toevoegen') }}` doesn't work in blade.

Is there a solution for this? I don't want to type the url in my method, becuase of it has to be variable.

**View**

```
<?= Authorize::createButton('Nieuwe school', array('scholen', 'toevoegen'), null, 'btn btn-primary'); ?>
```

**Helper Class**

```
static function createButton($text = null, $route = null, $id = null, $class = null)
{

        $button = '<a href="{{ URL::to(<!URL!>) }}"><button class="<!CLASS!>"><!TEXT!></button></a>';

        if ($text != null) {
            $button = str_replace("<!TEXT!>", $text, $button);
        } 

        if ($route[0] != null && $route[1] != null) {
            $button = str_replace("<!URL!>", $route[0] .'/'. $route[1] . ($id != null ? '/'. $id : ''), $button);
        } 

        if ($class != null) {
            $button = str_replace("<!CLASS!>", $class, $button);
        }

        return $button;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest evaluated the route variables within the `createButton()` method, rather than in Blade - like this:

```
$button = '<a href="' . URL::to($someConstructedRoute) . '"><button class="<!CLASS!>"><!TEXT!></button></a>';
```

Now, all we need is to create the constructed route above that code.

However, I also think there's considerable room for improvement in your method with e.g. `sprintf()`. It also seems that the route should never actually be empty, because you always want a real link. Here's an example of how I might change it - but it's just a suggestion.

```
static function createButton($routeVars, $text = '', $id = null, $class = '')
{
    $route = implode('/', $routeVars);
    if ($id) $route .= '/' . $id;
    $url = URL::to($route);

    return sprintf('<a href="%s"><button class="%s">%s</button></a>', 
        $url, $class, $text
    );
}
```

By changing the nulls to empty strings, we can just include them as is. If there's no text provided, for instance, the button will look like `<a href="somelink"><button class="someclass"></button></a>` with no text.

Actually, I would probably extract the three route creation to a static method as well, but that might be a bit nitpicky.

Hope this helps. :)